# How to connect Object Storage to a .php app in IBM Cloud (Bluemix)

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I have a Cloud Foundry PHP App and I have it bound to an Object Storage Cloud Foundry Service. In my php app I want to have a simple video cointainer but I want the actual video FILE to be stored in the Object Storage Cloud Foundry Service. I basically want to do something like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="my_video.MP4" type="video/mp4">
  Sorry, your browser doesn't support the video element.
</video>
```

But I don't know how to establish the connection or what the source path would be to the file located in my Object Storage Cloud Foundry Service.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a working example on Github.Just pointing to a link .
https://github.com/christiancompton/php-objectstorage

Even I am trying to achieve same thing.Hope it helps

Comment: Do let me know if it works ;-) .Its throwing an exception when I try to run it.